# unbounded variation of $\sin(x)/x$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, estimation

How can I show that the variation of $sin(x)/x$ is unbounded?
Could you please help me. I know that I have to use

[image]

but how can I rough estimate that this is bigger than infinity?

Comment: Are you familiar with any summations that are unbounded?  Perhaps related to $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots$.  Can you think of when the $\sin(x)$ part of $\sin(x)/x$ is irrelevant, perhaps equal to one, negative one, or zero?

Comment: Consider the partition $\{\frac{\pi}{2}i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} $